# Theorem of Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and differentiable in $(a,b)$.

Prove that there exists $ \alpha\in (a,b)$ such that

$$\frac{b f(a) -a f(b)}{b-a} = f(\alpha) - \alpha f'(\alpha).$$

Comment: I assume you mean $\alpha \in (a,b)$

Comment: Yes thanks. I made a mistake

Comment: Share your ideas/thoughts also rather than just posting the question. What have you tried?

Comment: There exists $\alpha \in [a,b]$ but not necessarily $\alpha\in (a,b).$  Let $f(x)=x^2, a=0,b=1.$ Then the  LHS is $0 $ and  the RHS is $-\alpha^2.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $u(x)=\frac{f(x)}x$ and $v(x)=\frac1x$ and consider the term
$$
\frac{u(a)-u(b)}{v(a)-v(b)}
$$
and the application of the extended mean value theorem to it.

Comment: This works only when $[a, b] $ does not contain $0$. But nice approach. +1

Comment: In fact the result in question is false when $[a, b] $ contains $0$. See counter-example given in comments to the question by user254665.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $bf(a)-af(b)=(f(a)+f(b))(b-a)+af(a)-bf(b)$

Now define $g(x)=xf(x)$ as an auxiliary function.